# Using @RequestLine with Feign

Tags: java, netflix-feign

I have a working Feign interface defined as:

```
@FeignClient("content-link-service")
public interface ContentLinkServiceClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{trackid}/links")
    List<Link> getLinksForTrack(@PathVariable("trackid") Long trackId);

}
```

If I change this to use @RequestLine

```
@FeignClient("content-link-service")
public interface ContentLinkServiceClient {

    @RequestLine("GET /{trackid}/links")
    List<Link> getLinksForTrack(@Param("trackid") Long trackId);

}
```

I get the exception

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method getLinksForTrack not annotated with HTTP method type (ex. GET, POST)

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I wouldn't expect this to work.

`@RequestLine` is a core Feign annotation, but you are using the Spring Cloud `@FeignClient` which uses Spring MVC annotations.

Answer (score 24):

Spring has created their own Feign `Contract` to allow you to use Spring's `@RequestMapping` annotations instead of Feigns. You can disable this behavior by [including a bean of type `feign.Contract.Default` in your application context](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/362).

If you're using `spring-boot` (or anything using Java config), including this in an `@Configuration` class should re-enable Feign's annotations:

```
@Bean
public Contract useFeignAnnotations() {
    return new Contract.Default();
}
```

Comment: And where exactly in the code we should call useFeignAnnotations(). Or is there an internal bean that will read useFeignAnnotations()? I have this problem and added the bean in my config, but as expected it does nothing

Comment: I'm also curious about this^

Answer (score 3):

The reason I got this error is that I used both `@FeignClient` and  `@RequestLine` annotations in my `FooClient` interface.

#### Before a fix.

```java
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient; // @FeignClient
import feign.RequestLine; //  @RequestLine
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

@FeignClient("foo")
public interface FooClient {

    @RequestLine("GET /api/v1/foos/{fooId}")
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    ResponseEntity getFooById(@PathVariable("fooId") Long fooId); // I mistakenly used @PathVariable annotation here, but this should be @Param
}
```

Then, I got this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method FooClient#getFooById(Long) not annotated with HTTP method type (ex. GET, POST)
```

#### After a fix

```java
// removed @FeignClient
// removed @PathVariable
import feign.Param; // Added
import feign.RequestLine; //  @RequestLine

// removed @FeignClient("foo")
public interface FooClient {

    @RequestLine("GET /api/v1/foos/{fooId}")
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    Foo getFooById(@Param("fooId") Long fooId); // used @Param
}
```

#### If you are interested in the configuration classes.

- Please note that I tried to create Feign Clients Manually.

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScans;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScans(value = {
        @ComponentScan(basePackages = {
                "com.example.app.service.web.client",
        })
})
public class FeignConfig {
    @Value(value = "${app.foo.service.client.url}")
    protected String url; // http://localhost:8081/app

    @Bean
    public FooClient fooClient() {
        FooClient fooClient = Feign.builder()
//                .client(RibbonClient.create())
                .client(new OkHttpClient())
                .encoder(new GsonEncoder())
                .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
                .logger(new Slf4jLogger(FooClient.class))
                .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
                .target(FooClient.class, url);
        return fooClient;
    }
}
```

#### References

1. https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html
2. https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-feign
3. https://www.baeldung.com/feign-requestline
4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32488372/12898581

Answer (score -1):

Your `@RequestMapping` value looks ok, but you're likely should consider slightly rewriting it:

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/{trackid}/links")
 List<Link> getLinksForTrack(@PathVariable(name = "trackid") Long trackId);
```

Btw I did not succeeded with getting `@RequestLine` to work due to same error as yours.

Also for `@ReactiveFeignClients` `Contract.Default()` yields to following errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method MyClient#doStuff(String,String) not annotated with HTTP method type (ex. GET, POST)
Warnings:
- Class MyClient has annotations [Component, ReactiveFeignClient, Metadata] that are not used by contract Default
- Method doStuff has an annotation GetMapping that is not used by contract Default
```

and should be fixed like:

```
var MyClient = WebReactiveFeign.builder()
        .contract(new ReactiveContract(new SpringMvcContract()))
        .target(MyClient, "http://example.com")
```