# Empty parameter in spring cloud feign client

Tags: spring-cloud-feign

I have a trouble with `spring-cloud-openfeign-core` after update from version `2.1.1` to version `2.1.2`.

When I perform a call with an empty parameter it always adds its name to a query string that was not the case before. 
The generated url in `2.1.1` is `http://test.url/endpoint` but in `2.1.2` it becomes   `http://test.url/endpoint?id` with `?id` at the end.

```java
// request
myFeignClient.myGetRequest(List.of())

// client
@FeignClient(name = "client", url = "http://test.url/")
public interface MyFeignClient {

    @RequestLine("GET /endpoint?id={id}")
    Object get(@Param(value = "id") List<String> id);
}
```

Is there any way to get rid of empty parameters names?

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't expect this to work. [Have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32488372/10383493)

And you should try this in client feign:

```
@GetMapping("/endpoint")
@ResponseBody
Object get(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) List<String> id);
```

Server :

```
@GetMapping("/endpoint")
Object get(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) List<String> id) {
     //...
}
```